# SimpleCart.js search functionality

Tags: simplecart

Have been using simpleCart for a while and it works great and i know it has a search function in it but it only seems to search certain elements my question is this, i would like to know if it can be set up to search within the contents of html files? as all the items are stored in Html pages for simple cataloging.

Answer (score 0):

try this: JS

```
            function filter(e){
                      search = e.value.toLowerCase();
                      console.log(e.value)
                      document.querySelectorAll('.item_name').forEach(function(row){
                         text = row.innerText.toLowerCase();
                         if(text.match(search)){
                            row.style.display="block"
                         } else {
                            row.style.display="none"
                         }

                          // need to count hidden items and if all instances of .kb-items are hidden, then hide .kb-item
                         var countHidden = document.querySelectorAll(".item_name[style='display: none;']").length;

                          console.log(countHidden);
                      })
                    }
                  function detectParent()
                  {
                    var collectionref=document.querySelectorAll(".simpleCart_shelfItem");
                    collectionref.forEach(group=>{
                      var itemcollection=group.getElementsByClassName("item_name");
                      var hidecounter=0;
                      for(var j=0;j<itemcollection.length;j++)
                      {

                        if(itemcollection[j].style.display==='none')
                        {
                            hidecounter++;
                        }
                      }
                      if(hidecounter===itemcollection.length)
                      {
                        group.style.display="none";
                      }else{
                        group.style.display="block";
                      }

                    });
                  }
```

And HTML:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="filter(this);detectParent();"/>
```